# babel-register is unable to transform react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, babel-register

I am trying to use react in node js application.
One way I found was using babel-register, which supposedly transform react jsx files.

I put code in node index.js.

```
require('babel-register')({
   ignore:'node_modules',
   presets: ["es2015",'react', "stage-0"],
   extensions: [".es6", ".es", ".jsx", ".js"]
});

app.use('/static', express.static('public'));


app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile(__dirname+'/public/index.html');
});

const server = app.listen(9000, () => {
    let port = server.address().port;
    winston.info(`Server running at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

Then I put react code in public/index.js

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDom = require('react-dom');
class TodoApp extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>Heslssddddlo</h1>
            </div>
        )}
}
ReactDom.render(
    <div>
        <TodoApp></TodoApp>
    </div>
    , document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Then I get this error. **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <**

I believe I installed everything I need to use babel-register...

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.11.4",
    "babel-core": "^6.11.4",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.11.6",
```

Do I have to use webpack rather than babel-register or I am doing it wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think babel register just makes it so you can 'require' a file and have babel transpile it. You are merely telling express to serve the file "as is" with express.static.

You will want to either use static to serve a file which has already been processed by babel, or require it. You may want to look into some of the react express view libraries.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to use babel register but did not work. Therefore, I am just using webpack and nodemon for my app.